# output as a list in Python

Tags: python

I have a file called localhosts, which is

```
vagrant1 ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2200
vagrant2 ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2200
vagrant3 ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2200
vagrant4 ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2200
vagrant5 ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2200
vagrant6 ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2200
vagrant7 ansible_ssh_host=127.0.0.1 ansible_ssh_port=2200
```

and, I want to `cat localhosts` inside python and put the output inside a list like below

```
MACHINE = ['vagrant1', 'vagrant2', 'vagrant3', 'vagrant4',
           'vagrant5','vagrant6','vagrant7'].
```

So far, I have

```
import os
os.system("cat localhosts")
```

How can I do it?, and I am trying to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
>>> with open('file.txt') as f:
...     MACHINE = [line.split()[0] for line in f]
... 
>>> MACHINE
['vagrant1', 'vagrant2', 'vagrant3', 'vagrant4', 'vagrant5', 'vagrant6', 'vagrant7']
```

---

If you must simulate Linux commands:

```
>>> MACHINE = subprocess.check_output(['cut', '-d ', '-f1', 'file.txt']).split()

>>> MACHINE
[b'vagrant1', b'vagrant2', b'vagrant3', b'vagrant4', b'vagrant5', b'vagrant6', b'vagrant7']
```

Here i am doing:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 file.txt
```

Comment: You need to define `MACHINE` outside of the with scope.

Comment: I want to `cat localhosts` command in Linux with Python environment instead of using `open`

Comment: @heemayl, if you know that way, can you show me how to do it.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, It is not required , redundant because `with` statement does not create new scope.

Comment: Because I want to write a script which to use `import os or import subprocess` to use Linux command

Comment: @heemayl, Actually I figured it out by replacing `open` by `os.popen`

Answer (score 1):

Try this

`os.system` only run the command into the python script. But your problem you want to store the linux command result into the variable. so try to use `commands` or `subprocess`

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import commands
import re
filename = "input.txt"


extract  = (commands.getstatusoutput("cat %s"%(filename)))[1].split("\n")

machine = []
for i in extract:
    j = re.match("^(\w+)",i)
    machine.append(j.group(1))

print machine
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

machines_temp = Popen('cat localhosts', shell=True, bufsize=4096, stdout=PIPE).stdout.read().strip().split('\n')
machines = [x.split() for x in machines]
print([x[0] for x in machines])
```

This should suffice

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess

catter = subprocess.Popen(['cat', 'localhost'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
cutter = subprocess.Popen(['cut', '-d', ' ', '-f1'], stdin=catter.stdout, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
MACHINES = cutter.communicate()[0].split('\n')
```